# how to build reactjs files for nginx using ansbile & then rsyncing those files to ansible inventory?

Tags: reactjs, docker, ansible

I have a ReactJS app, from which I got to build asset files for webserver. For this approach I use Docker container.

Container In Use: `node:12-alpine`
App Data: `./app` which will then be mounted to `/app` in container.

So I can build these js files by running a docker container directly like so

```
# docker container run -ti --name builder \
-v $PWD/app:/app -w /app node:12-alpine \
sh -c "apk update -qq && \
apk add git -qq && \
NODE_ENV=development npm install && \
mkdir dist && \
npm run build:staging"
```

Now I'm trying to automate all of this with ansible, so here are the tasks

```
- name: Run Container
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ container }}"
    image: "{{ image }}"
    volumes: "{{ lookup('env', 'PWD') }}/app:/app"
    working_dir: "/app"
    command: "{{ command }}"
    state: present
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Update Frontend
  synchronize:
    src: "{{ lookup('env', 'PWD') }}/{{ component }}/dist/"
    dest: "/{{ parent }}/{{ component }}"
    archive: no
    compress: yes
    recursive: yes
    delete: yes
```

Here are some of variables used in command

```
image: "node:12-alpine"
container: "builder"
command: "docker container exec -ti {{ container }} sh -c builder.sh"
```

the container runs, but it seems it does not run the specified command,
the builder.sh carries same commands used to compile

```
# cat builder.sh
apk update -qq
apk add git -qq
NODE_ENV=development npm install
mkdir dist
npm run build:staging
```

Do I have to make `builder.sh` executeable or missing something else?
Also, I want `synchronize` module to execute after build process is finished in container. what's method to do that?

Comment: It seems like it'd be easier to use Node directly; you can ask Ansible to install it (using an `apt` or `brew` action) if you don't already have it.  If you really need to use a `docker_container:`, the `command:` is the single process the container runs, which should just be `./builder.sh`; it's not a `docker exec`.

Comment: @DavidMaze ok it didnt work either by `./builder.sh` or `sh -c builder.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DockerFile with this parts.

```
# cat builder.sh
apk update -qq
apk add git -qq
NODE_ENV=development npm install
mkdir dist
```

```yaml
- name: Run Container
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ container }}"
    image: "{{ image }}"
    volumes: "{{ lookup('env', 'PWD') }}/app:/app"
    working_dir: "/app"
    recreate: yes
    command: "npm run build:staging"
    state: started
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Update Frontend
  synchronize:
    src: "{{ lookup('env', 'PWD') }}/{{ component }}/dist/"
    dest: "/{{ parent }}/{{ component }}"
    archive: no
    compress: yes
    recursive: yes
    delete: yes
```